# Create a UWP app MS-Teams like Left Pane/Tab UI control

Tags: uwp, xamarin.uwp

I use the Microsoft Teams app and am designing a with similar UI. But unable to find a control in UWP that looks like it. Can someone point me in the right direction.

I'll be designing it in Xamarin.UWP but any native help is also appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> But unable to find a control in UWP that looks like it. Can someone point me in the right direction.

You could custom it with [SplitView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.splitview?view=winrt-19041) control and place listview in the `Pane` content. And you could also use [`NavigationView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview) control that integrate `SplitView` as root view.

For more please refer this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview). And here is  [code sample here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/navigationview#examples).

If you has used Xamarin.Forms project, you could use [shell navigation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/shell/navigation) control to implement  this feature. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-xaminals/) is code sample that contains UWP platform.